# set acl permission for delete button on customer view

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to set ACL permission for delete button on customer view Page in admin panel

[image]

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 3 things to do.

1. Add new ACL
2. Disable the `Delete Customer` Button
3. Disable the Action if someone call the url `admin/customer/delete/id/1` manuelly

## 1. Add new ACL

Create a new `adminhtml.xml` in your Module in the `etc/` Folder or extend your existing `adminhtml.xml` with this code:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <customer translate="title" module="customer">
                    <children>
                        <delete translate="title">
                            <title>Delete Customer</title>
                            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
                        </delete>
                    </children>
                </customer>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

We extended the existing `<customer>` node with our `<delete>` node.
If you flush your cache, you already see a new entry in the Role Resources.

## 2. Disable the Button

We have to rewrite the core Block and delete the Button. Add the rewrite in your config.xml in your `<block>` node:

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <customer_edit>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit</customer_edit>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Create a new File in the `Block/` Folder: `adminhtml/Cutomer/Edit.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/customer/delete')) {
            $this->_removeButton('delete');
        }

    }

}
```

We check if the Permission is set for the User. If not, we remove the Button.

## 3. Disable the Action

In your config.xml you have to add a new adminhtml event:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_customer_delete>
            <observers>
                <delete_customer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <method>checkCustomerDelete</method>
                    <class>company_name/observer</class>
                </delete_customer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_customer_delete>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

The Event is called if before the code inside the Action is executed.
Create or extend `Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Name_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkCustomerDelete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/customer/delete')) {
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone call the URL manually, the script just stops the request. It would be better if you show the User a Message and redirect them to the previous site.

The last thing you have to do is, delete the cache :)